# MongoDB Fluent interface. Attempting to project a sub-documents properties, whilst ignoring the parent documents properties

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a parent document that contains a sub document (it's not an array, just a 1:1 relationship).

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(....)
  prop1 : value1
  prop2 : value2
  subdoc : {
    subProp1 : subPropValue1
    subProp2 : subPropValue2
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to use Projections to include just subProp1 and subProp2. I can get this working via the MongCLI but cannot get the equivalent working in C# (fluent interface). I've tried silliness like chaining together Projections (exclude & include). But the later overrides the former. Eventually I'd like the map the sub document contents to a C# Entity object.

The projections are created thus: Builders.Projection.Exclude(..).Exclude().....
Also tried creating the projections via a BsonDocument.

```
collection.Find<BsonDocument>(filter).Project("{ _id:0, prop1:0, prop2:0, subdoc : { subprop1:1, subprop2:1 }}")
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.